# "Get an eye for somebody" VS "Eyeing someone"

Tags: idioms, expressions

> 1) Lucas is totally into you. Whenever a guy buys something so expensive it means he .......... 
>   2) We are just friends Nancy. Why are you looking at me that way?! 
>   1) Me and you both know the truth. Just be careful. You don't know him yet.

a. [has got an eye for you](https://www.ldoceonline.com/dictionary/have-an-eye-a-good-eye-for-something) 
b. [eyeing you](https://www.ldoceonline.com/dictionary/eye-up)

Please let me know what is the difference between these two idioms and which one for what reason is more appropriate in this case?

To me, according to the dictionary definitions, they both make a perfect sense here.

Comment: I don't see a definition for a) that would make sense here. B) would be my choice.

Comment: Well @Micah Windsor, then why in this link (https://www.google.com/amp/s/www.wattpad.com/amp/877022934) the writer said "He has got an eye for you"? Do you see it as a mistake?

Comment: Ah yes, Wattpad. The most authoritative grammar source you could possibly choose. It's probably a mistake.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The dictionary definitions to which you refer actually differ slightly.

*Have an eye/a good eye for something* means that someone is **good at** noticing something. The dictionary definition gives the following example sentences:

> Ernest **has an eye for** detail. *(Ernest **is good at noticing** detail.)*
>
> She’s definitely got a good eye for a bargain. (*She **is good at noticing/spotting** a bargain.)*

*Eyeing something/someone* doesn't refer to **ability**, like the first one does. It refers to **a way that** someone looks at someone they are attracted to or something that they like/desire.

> He is **eyeing you**. (*He **is looking at** you **in a way that shows that he is attracted to you**.)*
>
> I'm **eyeing this watch**. *(I'm **looking at** this watch **in a way that shows I like it and/or want it**.)*

Comment: But @Kman3 I've heard the sentence "he has got an eye for ladies" about a lustful man who was attracted to all gorgeous women. How would you define it here?

Comment: @A-friend  Since, in some male social circles, it is seen as a "talent" to form relationships with beautiful women, he's got "an eye for ladies" because he has this "talent" -- he's _**good at noticing** gorgeous women_.

Comment: Well @Kman3 I see. Well, let me clarify my intention bringing up another scenario. Two close friends are talking to each other. One of them says: "my husband doesn't seem to be  interest to me anymore. He often gets home late and often texts on his phone." Her friend says: "Maybe, he **has got an eye for someone else** (another woman)." Or "Maybe, he **is eyeing someone else** (another woman)." Which one seems to be correct here?

Comment: @A-friend Out of your two sentences, the second one seems to be correct. You could say "_has got **his** eye **on** someone else_" instead to show that the husband has interest in another woman.

Comment: Aha Kman3. The  just let me know how these two sentences differ in meaning? "He has got **an** eye for someone else" VS "He has got **his** eye for someone else"

Comment: @A-friend Read the last part again. He has got his eye **ON** someone else. Not **for**. This is the reason why these are different. The preposition matters.

Comment: I see @Kman3. Just can we omit "his" in "He has got his eye on someone else" and say "He has got an eye on someone else" or it is a fixed term and I cannot use "an" instead of "his"?

Comment: @A-friend From what I can find, both seem to work. I think using a possessive pronoun works best (_your_, _his_, _their_...), but I guess that's personal preference. See [this source](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/have-your-eye-on-something) and [this source](https://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/have+an+eye+on).

Comment: Aha, then in my original question I could definitely say: "**He has got an / his eye on you**". So the correct answer would be "A" with changing the preposition from "for" to "on". Do you confirm @Kman3?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/108206/discussion-between-kman3-and-a-friend).

Comment: @A-friend The expression is actually 'He has an eye for _the_ ladies'. Opinions seem to differ as to whether it means he is promiscuous or just an admirer of female beauty.

Comment: Well @Kate Bunting the problem is that there are four scenarios with quite close semantic prosody. I have raised them in the chat with Kman3. May I ask you to do me a great favor and help me with them. It seems that English speakers use different sentences in similar cases. In my mother tongue I use one single sentence for them all! But perhaps, it differs in English.

Comment: If you _have your eye on_ something or someone, it can mean that you are watching to make sure it is safe, or that a child is not misbehaving - or it can mean that you would like to possess it. If you are _eyeing someone up_, you fancy them as a romantic/sexual partner.